# Tab Bar controller

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

How many tab I can add on one tab bar controller  ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as many as you want - any more than 5 and there will be displayed a "more" tab in the 5th place which will let users choose which tabs they want to see on the Tab bar controller, but all will be accessible.